# Convert Unix Timestamp to DateTime based on users Timezone

Tags: asp.net-mvc, calendar, unix-timestamp

I want to convert a UNIX Timestamp into DateTime for my ASP .NET Webapplication.
There are quite some answers regarding this issue. But so far I couldn't figure out, how to convert the Timestamp into a DateTime based on the Users location.
The Application is a Calendar, which is used from Europe, America and India.

Is there a way to detect the Timezone the user is currently in and convert the timestamp accordingly? I also need to take the Daylight-saving into consideration.

This is my code so far:

```
public DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
    {
        TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
        DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        DaylightTime daylight = localZone.GetDaylightChanges(origin.AddSeconds(timestamp).Year);
        return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp).Add(daylight.Delta);
    }
```

But this does not work for the users outside from Europe.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The chief problem with your code is that you're never actually utilizing the timezone. It is factored into figuring out if it's daylight savings or not, but never to actually modify the returned datetime. However, your code here is overly complex anyways. If all you're looking for is to convert this to local server time, all you need is:

```
new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(timestamp).ToLocalTime();
```

The default kind for `DateTime` is UTC, which is what you want in this case since UNIX timestamps are measured from UTC.

**EDIT**

Technically, since `DateTime` will default the time portion to 00:00:00.0000, anyways. You can just do `DateTime(1970, 1, 1)`, as well.

Comment: oh, that's what you get for copy-pasting code blindly ... I'll have a short test and as soon as I have feedback from India, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: So I finally had a change to check the displayed times in India. It shows the European times, not the local times...